# Jquery Select all IDs in different Sections

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have 2 same IDs inside 2 different sections.  When the button is clicked, I want it selects the id inside this section and apply a style, then it will select the id in a different section and apply that style, as well.

My sample below just works inside the first section.  Please give a hand.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#clickMe').click(function() {
      $('#square').css('background-color', 'red');
    })
});
```

```css
.block {width: 100%; padding-bottom: 40px;}
#square {width: 80px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid gray}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  This is block 1
  <button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
  <div id="square"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  This is block 2
  <div id="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the same DOM, so the question is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The same ID should only be once per page. If you have multiple the DOM only attaches the attributes to the first ID thats found with that name.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#clickMe').click(function() {
      $('.square').css('background-color', 'red');
    })
});
```

```css
.block {width: 100%; padding-bottom: 40px;}
.square {width: 80px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid gray}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  This is block 1
  <button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  This is block 2
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```